# keep gettext catalogs up to date

Tags: node.js, gettext, i18next

I have a node.js project and I am using I18next to localize it, with the gettext http://i18next.com/node/pages/doc_init.html#gettext backend.

My template engine i am using with this project is https://github.com/bminer/node-blade which is similar to jade.

Then I use the https://www.npmjs.org/package/i18next-parser library with `i18next -r -o ../tmp -l en` command to extract all the msgid's and create a dev.json file.

Once this is done, i use `i18next-conv -l en -s ../dev.json -t dev.po` to convert this to a gettext format.

From this I would create a fr.po file and then get this translated to french, as an example.

So far this process works fine, the question is, how best to keep all the msgid's should for example, I need to add new strings to the catalog and then merge these into the fr.po file without loosing any strings which have already been translated?

any advice much appreciated.